# Why several blocks are not working after cloning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I apologize if the question is formulated sloppy. I'm just somewhere in the beginning of understanding jquery.

I want to implement a form builder based on drag and drop.

I added button to clone dropped element.
But after cloning "remove" and "clone" buttons are not working.

jsfiddle.net/284mx1vn/

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just adjusted your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/284mx1vn/1/)

I've added the two lines

```
$(document).on("click", ".remove", function(){
  $(this).closest(".input-block").remove();});
$(document).on("click", ".add", function(){
  $(this).closest(".input-block").clone().appendTo("#drop-space");
});
```

so it works for dynamically created elements, and added the class "add" to the "add"-button for convenience.
The issue was/is that events have to be bound to elements already existing in the DOM when the document is loaded. As solution it is possible to use event delegation - meaning to delegate the event (in this case the click event for the buttons) from a static parent element, e.g. `$(document)`. This parent element will delegate the event to all children of the class using the jquery `on()` function, even if these elements are added later.
For reference: http://api.jquery.com/on/ and https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler, section "Direct and delegated events":

> "Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on()."

Comment: thanks, but why is it add two copies at first click?

Comment: @fte The double on first click is just your original appending / removing attached to the click when you clone the divs. Those already but only worked for the first added block and can just be removed.

Comment: @fte Glad to be of help, and thx for the info, as I was just adjusting the Fiddle to remove the doubles on first.